# Trouble getting text from <textarea> using ReactJS

Tags: forms, reactjs, textarea

I'm new to react and I am just trying to create a text box that takes user input and alerts that input onto the screen. I was using [this](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#the-textarea-tag) for reference. My problem is that when I try to alert or log the userInput nothing happens. When I alert just a normal string in the handleSubmit function it works just fine, but with this.state.userInput nothing happens.
Here is my code:

```
export class InputText extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {userInput: ""};
  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  this.handleSumbit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event){
    this.setState({userInput: event.target.value})
  }
  handleSubmit(){
    console.log(this.state.userInput);
    alert(this.state.userInput);

  }
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
      <form>
        <textarea onChange = {this.handleChange} value = {this.state.userInput}></textarea>
        <button type = 'button' onClick = {this.handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
      </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: do you mean handleSubmit method is not working? you don't see any log or alert?

Comment: it works if I do alert("test") but I don't get a log or an alert with alert(this.state.userInput)

Comment: Spelling error: `this.handleSumbit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);`. See: `Sumbit`

Comment: @RickJolly you are correct.

Comment: @RickJolly yep now it works just fine. Now I feel dumb for spending so much time trying to figure out why it wasn't working

Comment: @WebbH definitely hard to spot. Had to paste into Codepen and figure it out from the error in the console.